# how to set a flag in a stored procedure if the record is null display it else don't display it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to set a flag in a stored procedure if the record's effect date is null, display it, else ObsDate don't display it. Here is my SP it gets the latest date. Do I need to add another column to my table?

```
SELECT
  StudentNames.LName,
  StudentNames.FName,
  MAX(StudentNames.EffDate) AS Date,
  StudentNames.ObsDate,
  StudentNames.StudentID
FROM StudentNames
GROUP BY 
  StudentNames.LName,
  StudentNames.FName,
  StudentNames.ObsDate,
  StudentNames.StudentID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking. You need a CASE statement.

```
SELECT
  StudentNames.LName,
  StudentNames.FName,
  MAX(StudentNames.EffDate) AS Date,
  --Begin Case statement. Check if EffDate is null
  CASE WHEN StudentNames.EffDate IS NULL 
        THEN StudentNames.ObsDate 
        ELSE NULL END AS 'ObsDate',
  --End Case statement
  StudentNames.StudentID
FROM StudentNames
GROUP BY 
  StudentNames.LName,
  StudentNames.FName,
  StudentNames.ObsDate,
  StudentNames.StudentID
```

If your intent is to combine both the date columns, you could do this.

```
SELECT
  StudentNames.LName,
  StudentNames.FName,
  --Begin Case statement. Check if EffDate is null
  CASE WHEN StudentNames.EffDate IS NULL 
        THEN StudentNames.ObsDate 
        ELSE MAX(StudentNames.EffDate) END AS 'Date',
  --End Case statement
  StudentNames.StudentID
FROM StudentNames
GROUP BY 
  StudentNames.LName,
  StudentNames.FName,
  StudentNames.ObsDate,
  StudentNames.StudentID
```

Comment: You can't use different data types in the same field, like dates and strings.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks James.

Comment: It works, had to add a Where clause: WHERE StudentNames.StudentID = StudentIDs.StudentID
AND StudentNames.ObsDate IS NULL